# How to display images and embed in the transcript file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm making a ticket bot where a user creates a ticket and then gets the support they need then after an admin or the same user closes the ticket a transcript will be saved and sent in the same channel and I've already done that but the only thing I'm struggling at is displaying Embeds and Images in that transcript log. Now it looks like this (Copy paste it to see):

file:///G:/BotTickets/Akeoe%20792817221239832627.html

I figured maybe the image would help you understand more, all the bots( ASOG ) messages is Embeds and it looks like that with images too

Code of how I save and display:

````
let messageCollection = new Discord.Collection();
let channelMessages = await channel.messages.fetch({
    limit: 100
}).catch(err => console.log(err));
                                        
messageCollection = messageCollection.concat(channelMessages);
                                        
while(channelMessages.size === 100) 
{
    let lastMessageId = channelMessages.lastKey();
    channelMessages = await channel.messages.fetch()({ limit: 100, before: lastMessageId }).catch(err => console.log(err));
    if(channelMessages)
        messageCollection = messageCollection.concat(channelMessages);
}

let msgs = messageCollection.array().reverse();
let data = await fs.readFile('./commands/template.html', 'utf8').catch(err => console.log(err));
if(data) 
{
    await fs.writeFile(`G:\BotTickets/${ticketUserusername + ` ` + channel.id}.html`, data).catch(err => console.log(err));
    let guildElement = document.createElement('div');
    let guildText = document.createTextNode(message.guild.name);
    let guildImg = document.createElement('img');
    guildImg.setAttribute('src', message.guild.iconURL());
    guildImg.setAttribute('width', '150');
    guildElement.appendChild(guildImg);
    guildElement.appendChild(guildText);
    console.log(guildElement.outerHTML);
    await fs.appendFile(`G:\BotTickets/${ticketUserusername + ` ` + channel.id}.html`, 
    guildElement.outerHTML).catch(err => console.log(err));
                                        
    msgs.forEach(async msg => {
        let parentContainer = document.createElement("div");
        parentContainer.className = "parent-container";
                                        
        let avatarDiv = document.createElement("div");
        avatarDiv.className = "avatar-container";
        let img = document.createElement('img');
        img.setAttribute('src', msg.author.displayAvatarURL());
        img.className = "avatar";
        avatarDiv.appendChild(img);
                                        
        parentContainer.appendChild(avatarDiv);
                                        
        let messageContainer = document.createElement('div');
        messageContainer.className = "message-container";
                                        
        let nameElement = document.createElement("span");
        let name = document.createTextNode(msg.author.tag + " " + msg.createdAt.toDateString() + " " + 
        msg.createdAt.toLocaleTimeString() + " EST");
        nameElement.appendChild(name);
        messageContainer.append(nameElement);
                                        
        if(msg.content.startsWith("```")) 
        {
            let m = msg.content.replace(/```/g, "");
            let codeNode = document.createElement("code");
            let textNode =  document.createTextNode(m);
            codeNode.appendChild(textNode);
            messageContainer.appendChild(codeNode);
        }
        else 
        {
            let msgNode = document.createElement('span');
            let textNode = document.createTextNode(msg.content);
            msgNode.append(textNode);
            messageContainer.appendChild(msgNode);
        }
        parentContainer.appendChild(messageContainer);
        await fs.appendFile(`G:\BotTickets/${ticketUserusername + ` ` + channel.id}.html`, 
    parentContainer.outerHTML).catch(err => console.log(err));
                                                        
 });
}
````

Comment: You didn't send the image as base64, but as a local path on your computer.